# Android browser scroll issues

Tags: android, browser, jquery-mobile

I am making a mobile website running with Jquery Mobile and the site is just like a big form split up in several pages. It works good with all phones except with Android.
The problem is when you focus on a input at the lower part of the page, you wont be able to scroll to see the last element of the page (Which in this case is the submit button) cause the keyboard blocks its display.

I've tried to find any sollution for this - f.o.e i tried to use iScroll without no success.
Is there any good sollutions to this?

Cheers

Comment: People can take the keyboard away by pressing back once, but never mind that, I'd recommend just adding empty space bellow to fix this easy.

Comment: Aha okay - well i'll try that out then. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue on our mobile site. What I ended up doing was hooking the input's focus event and blur events. In the focus event I dynamically increased the height of the page. In the blur event I restored the height. As a safety measure, I also restore the height on the page hide event.

Hope this helps. If needed I can provide more details.